# customizing jtable cellrenderer with table's cell header color

Tags: swing, colors, header, jtable, look-and-feel

That's a question really similar to this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571877/jtable-tablecellrenderer-background-with-nimbuslookandfeel-color-problem) of mine.
I need to customize some cell of a JTable, in a way that they would look like a table header cell.
I'm using Nimbus look and feel and I'm trying to retrieve the color of JTable's editor:

```
public class HeaderCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer{


    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        System.out.println("OK");
        this.setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(UIManager.getColor("TableHeader.background"));
        return this;
    }

}
```

I follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730649/swing-uimanager-getcolor-keys) to get the name to be supplied to getColor  method ("TableHeader.background").
Despite what I've done since now, the color returned isn't the same of my table's header cells.

Do you have any idea?

EDIT:

I noticed that instead of a color it should be a gradient but I can't find the right key to use. I looked [this list](http://nadeausoftware.com/node/85#TableHeader).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appearance of the default table header for a typical Look & Feel is provided by an instance of [`sun.swing.table.DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer`](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/swing/table/DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer.java.html). You can obtain a copy as follows:

```
class HeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

    TableCellRenderer renderer;

    public HeaderRenderer(JTable table) {
        renderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
        boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        return renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
            table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
    }
}
```

and you can install it in the usual way for a given column's [type token](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html):

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(SomeObject.class, new HeaderRenderer(table));
```

Comment: See also Darryl Burke's [*Default Table Header Cell Renderer*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/27/default-table-header-cell-renderer/).