# Creating a JTable with alternating row colors

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

[image]

I am pretty new to java swing and i just started working on JTable.  I want to create a JTable Which look like the above image? Can anybody help me beacause i am not so familiar with JTable?

Comment: What about the image do you want to replicate?  The header looks like it comes from the XP look and feel.  Candy stripping can be achieved by using cell renderers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding the `prepareRender(...)` method of the `JTable` allows you to customize rendering for the entire row without providing custom renderers.

The basic logic would be something like:

```
JTable table = new JTable( model )
{
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

        //  Alternate row color

        if (!isRowSelected(row))
            c.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? getBackground() : Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        return c;
    }
};
```

Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for more information and working examples.

Comment: How can i achieve the border of the table header like the figure?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I achieve the border of the table header like the figure?

You can obtain a copy of the default table header renderer for a given L&F, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6644956/230513), and modify it as desired. With some [caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7146216/230513), you can modify the renderer for a particular `TableColumn`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7137801/230513).